# Shortcut to lock camera to active view in macbook pro

Tags: animation, 2d

i been trying blender 2.83 on MACBOOK 2019 and I am not able to find replacement to numpad shortcuts. for locking to active camera view it is shift+ctrl+0, but it's not working on my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a numpad, you can emulate it using your number keys (the ones above the letters on your keyboard) by going into Edit>Preferences>Input and in the "Keyboard" section, check the "Emulate Numpad" checkbox.

Not sure what you are trying to do with Shift+Ctrl+0 but if you are trying to bring your camera to your current view, the shortcut that I had work is actually Ctrl+Alt+0

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey thanks!! That works

Comment: You can mark my answer as solution and close the topic then